# sql server 2012 allowing remote connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, networking, infrastructure

I want to connect asp.net application hosted at a web server with sql server 2012 db hosted at another remote location.
I have enabled the TCP/IP on sql server, also set port 6322 for ip1 and ipall.
but if i go to my web server and telnet into the db server, no connection is established.
in ASP.net page just to test the connection i am using the connection string as below

```
 <add name="DBConnectionStringTEST" 
 connectionString="Data Source=<db ip address>; Initial Catalog=<db name>; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;connection timeout=0;Max Pool Size = 100;Pooling = True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

my questions,

1) is there something i am missing, like wrong port.

2) do i need to give db ip address(client_net_address) or the actual db server address.

3) do i need to ask the server administrator to allow web server ip address to connect.

4) what is the quickest way to test if the web server can talk to the sql server without having to amend the connection string in asp.net application every time i make changes.

NOTE: i have searched other similar topic but couldnt find any answer which worked for me.

Comment: Are you running a named instance for your SQL Server?  If so you'll need to use that in your connection string (eg ServerName\InstanceName) for your `Data Source`

Comment: Does the firewall allow traffic through that port?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) is there something i am missing, like wrong port.

From your posted connection string it looks like you are using default instance. if it's indeed named instance then provide the same info in your connection string.

> 2) do i need to give db ip address(client_net_address) or the actual
>   db server address.

It should be actual DB server IP address/Hostname along with Db server installed instance name.

> 3) do i need to ask the server administrator to allow web server ip
>   address to connect.

If you are providing correct IP addr/hostname/port/credential then it should allow you to connect through. (provided your DB admin have already created DB user for you)

> 4) what is the quickest way to test if the web server can talk to the
>   sql server without having to amend the connection string in asp.net
>   application every time i make changes.

By creating a `UDL` file. Open a `notepad` and save it as `test.udl`. Once saved -> double click the file -> provide all info  and test the connection. It should look like below

[image]

**EDIT:**

To configure a universal data link (.udl) file

1. Double click on he file named `test.udl`
2. On `Provider` tab select `SQL Server Native client 10.0`
3. On `Connection` tab

   enter `BRR=SQL-N1` as `Server Name`

   In `Username` and `password` section provide `SA` and `password`

   Click on `Test Connection`

See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx) for more information on this.

Comment: i created the UDL file, but couldn't connect. Wanted to check if i am providing the correct information. i have got the following information(modified slightly to protect information) Local ServerName : BRR-CLUSTINT07\CLUSTRESOURCE02, Local Net Address: 10.170.7.103, Client Net Address(same as machine ip address): 10.170.7.1, Host Name of the machine where sql is installed : BRR=SQL-N1 , Username: SA , Password: password, local tcp port 6322, now given the above information rahul what should i write in source name ?

Comment: @HakanZim, see edited answer (mainly the `EDIT:` part

Comment: another thing which i have noticed. in order to access sql server, i remote desktop onto server1 and then remote desktop onto server2(sql server).If i go to server i and UDL test connection with the following, CLUSTINT07\CLUSTRESOURCE02 it WORKS. but may be because both server1 and server2 are in same environment or something.

Comment: @HakanZim, that's right. if you are testing connecion frm local machine then this won't work since you don't have a direct connection. You have to test the connection from your jump box.

Comment: i am trying from the web server which is hosted by a completed different hosting company. so are you saying that both db server and web server needs to be on the same env if not they cannot be connected ?

Comment: No, I am not saying that rather saying that your connection testing through UDL won't work from your local machine since per your comment you are connecting to Db server through an intermidieate server. So you wil have to test it from intermidieate server.

Comment: oh got it, the testing works with the intermediate server, but in real work i wont be connecting through intermediate server, the connection needs to be established between web server and db server, both at remote locations, i ideally i want to be able to test the connection from web server to db server.

Comment: You can, since WS will be having direc connection to DB server.

Comment: Hi Rahul, no i didnt work. the web server does not have any direct connection with the db server, the db server needs to be remotely connected and so far all my efforts didnt produce any result. i could connect from another server to the db server, but that server is also hosted by the same company as db server, but the web server cannot access the db server

Answer (score 1):

Without an explicit port or instance name specification, the default 1433 port will be used.  Specify your custom port in the connections string:

```
<add name="DBConnectionStringTEST" 
    connectionString="Data Source=<db server ip address or host name>,6322; Initial Catalog=<db name>; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;connection timeout=0;Max Pool Size = 100;Pooling = True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

An easy way to test network connectivity is with TELNET:

```
TELNET <db server ip address or host name> 6322
```

This will show an empty console window if successful.  Press ctrl-C to close.

You can also verify port connectivity with the Powershell command below if you don't have TELNET installed:

```
6322 | % { echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("<db server ip address or host name>",$_)) "server listening on TCP port $_" }
```

Comment: i tried both telnet and powershell, but couldn't connect. Wanted to check if i am providing the correct information. i have got the following information(modified slightly to protect information) Local ServerName : BRR-CLUSTINT07\CLUSTRESOURCE02, Local Net Address: 10.170.7.103, Client Net Address(same as machine ip address): 10.170.7.1, Host Name of the machine where sql is installed : BRR=SQL-N1 , Username: SA , Password: password, local tcp port 6322. given the above information what should be the commands for telnet or power shell?

Comment: Specify only the host name and omit the instance name.  The Powershell command to verify port connectivity is: 6322 | % { echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("BRR-CLUSTINT07",$_)) "server listening on TCP port $_" }

Comment: In your connection string, you can either specify "BRR-CLUSTINT07,6322" or "BRR-CLUSTINT07\CLUSTRESOURCE02" if CLUSTRESOURCE02 is your instance name.  Looking at the name, I suspect that CLUSTRESOURCE02 is the name of the cluster resource rather than the name of the instance.  The cluster resource name is should not be specified in the connection string.

Comment: Hi Dan, It is a clustered server so the resources could be shared between the two servers. so what should be the telnet command     i have already tried TELNET BRR-CLUSTINT07,6322  and TELNET BRR-CLUSTINT07\CLUSTRESOURCE02,6322 to no avail

Comment: another thing which i have noticed. in order to access sql server, i remote desktop onto server1 and then remote desktop onto server2(sql server). if i go to server i and UDL test connection with the following, CLUSTINT07\CLUSTRESOURCE02 it WORKS. but may be because both server1 and server2 are in same env or something